# Open single screen as modal in stackNavigator an others as cards

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `react-navigation` v3 in my `react-native` app.

I got a stackNavigator with different screens

```
const CarsListStack = createStackNavigator({
  CarsListScreen: { screen: CarsListScreen },
  FiltersScreen: { screen: FiltersScreen },
  CardDetailScreen: { screen: CardDetailScreen },
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'CarsListScreen',
});
```

I know that adding: `mode: 'modal` in the `createStackNavigator` options will make all the screens in the stack open from the bottom.

How can I make **only** the `CardDetailScreen` open from bottom and keep other screens in the stack open as usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to make another stack for the `CardDetailScreen`, so ;

```
    // Main Card-Style Navigator

      const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
      CarsListScreen: { screen: CarListScreen },
      FiltersScreen: { screen: FiltersScreen },
      CardDetailScreen: { screen: ModalStack },
    },
     { 
       initialRouteName:'CarsListScreen' 
   }); 

    // Modal-Style Navigator

     const ModalStack = StackNavigator({
      Home: { screen: MainStack },
      Modal: { screen: CarDetailScreen },
    }, {
      mode: 'modal',
     headerMode:'none',
    });
```